# Configuring pycharm for odoo

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to configure pycharm to run odoo. I've created a .conf file with the following contents.

odoo-server.conf

```
[options]
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_password = notebook
db_user = odoo20
xmlrpc_port = 8088
addons_path = home/mypc/PycharmProject/odoo/odoo-12.0/my_addons
```

when i try to run the project, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    import babel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel'
```

But i've done sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt which has babel in it, additionaly i've tried sudo pip3 install babel and it says requirement already satisfied. Where do i have to make changes?

**PS:** 
I am on Ubuntu 18.04 the pycharm project is using the interpreter inside the project(python 3.6). I have python 3.6 installed on ubuntu

Comment: Typically you have at least 2 different Python instances on your system.  Imho, to have an answer  you should add a bit of context...  are you on Win, Mac, Linux? what is the interpreter used by Pycharm? what is the system's Python? etc etc the more context the better answers... ciao **PS** forgot to mention, don't give additional info in a comment, please [edit] your question.

Comment: @gboffi ,Sorry , i've added the info to the question. Is it because i didn't install babel inside the environment? Used  pip3 to install the dependencies.

Comment: Make sure you are using the right Python interpreter check it in run configuration. try to run it using normal shell if you can then you are not using the right Interpreter that's all